# How should I structure a community contribution code repository and solution?

Tags: .net, open-source, codeplex

I'm getting ready to launch a contribution project on CodePlex to provide a place where people can write and share extensions for another project that I have on there.  This contrib project will be similar to the [MEF-Contrib project](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/) in that multiple people will be able to submit items to the project that extend the core application.

Now, I am attempting to focus on what the best way to organize the repository and solution might be.  I would like to imagine that there would be a very large amount of people adding stuff to the project and if it grows as such, I am wondering if a single DLL would be best.

Without truly knowing just how big some of the extensions that people will submit may be, do you think it would be better to treat each extension as a separate folder and project/assembly or should all of them be lumped into 1 large project like MEF-Contrib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an attempt to deploy "just what is needed" for a project into production, I would like to see one folder per extension.  That way extensions can be easily selected (or de-selected) for inclusion into projects.

Comment: This would definitely provide a simple way of getting only the code/modules you need and if you want to combine there's always ILMerge.  Very good point.

Answer (score 0):

Start off with a single DLL and break it off if it becomes too big. Just applying YAGNI here.